# Why does the keras model compile but the fit_generator command throws a 'model not compiled runtime error'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've set up a custom CNN with K-fold cross-validation in keras with tensorflow back-end. 
The model.compile() function is called before starting the training, but the model.fit_generator() function call results in an runtime error: "You must compile your model before using it."

I do data augmentation with ImageDataGenerator and use the fit_generator function for training.

The only related issue I've found up untill now had to do with the tensorflow [eager execution](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18287) feature which seems to not be enabled in Keras.

Here is the code:

model definition:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(24, (5, 5), 
          strides=(1, 1), 
          padding="valid", 
          data_format="channels_last",
          activation='relu', 
          use_bias=True,
          ))#out=96
model.add(Dropout(.25))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))#out=48
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), 
          strides=(1, 1), 
          padding="valid", 
          data_format="channels_last",
          activation='relu', 
          use_bias=True,
          ))#out=46
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))#out=23
model.add(Conv2D(48, (3, 3), 
          strides=(1, 1), 
          padding="valid", 
          data_format="channels_last",
          activation='relu', 
          use_bias=True,
          ))#out=21
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))#padding???
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

...here would be the data initialization...

setting up the ImageGenerator:

```
datagen_training = ImageDataGenerator(
            rotation_range = 20,
            width_shift_range = 0.3,
            height_shift_range=0.3,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            fill_mode = "constant",
            cval = 0,
            vertical_flip = True,
            validation_split = 0.2
            )
datagen_training.fit(data)
```

model setup and training:

```
rmsprop = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001)#docu says to only tune the learning rate
kf = KFold(n_splits=FOLDS, shuffle = True, random_state=78945)
model.compile(rmsprop, loss = losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy])
acc_hist = []
while True:
    history = object()
    for train_idx, val_idx in kf.split(data, labels):
        x_train, y_train = data[train_idx], labels[train_idx]
        x_val, y_val = data[val_idx], labels[val_idx]
        data_iterator = datagen_training.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
        history = model.fit_generator(data_iterator, steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // BATCH_SIZE, epochs=1)
    acc_hist.append(history.history['categorical_accuracy'][0])
    #stop if accuracy doesn't change within 3 epochs
    if stopping_criterion_met:
        break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model isn't compiling because it isn't being built, and it isn't being built because the `input_shape` isn't being specified in the first layer.  I'm not sure the input shape of your data, but something like this for your first layer would get the model to compile:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(24, (5, 5), 
      strides=(1, 1), 
      padding="valid", 
      data_format="channels_last",
      activation='relu', 
      use_bias=True,
      input_shape=(100,100,1)
      ))#out=96
```